# Help identify a ceiling mounted fluorescent light cover

Tags: light, cover

I know this is a stretch, but I'm hoping that someone might be able to help. I have three of these lights and two of the covers are broken. We've searched and been unable to find new ones. I don't know the brand, but I do know we bought them at Home Depot some time after 2006.

Included are images of the fixture.

Thanks in advance!

[image: four foot fluorescent fixture] [image: four foot fluorescent fixture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not an answer but it may help.

Many of Home Depot and Lowes labels on are not OEM's (Original Equipment Manufacturer). They are products manufactured then slapped with a Copyrighted Label owned by these companies. Ryobi and Hampton Bay are examples. So if you try and replace something like a lens you may run into trouble trying to get replacement parts especially if they were discontinued.

Good Luck

Comment: I'm starting to see that in a lot of the things we've replaced over the years. On top of that, there are no labels or serials anywhere on the cover. The markings on the light itself are for the manufacturer of the electrical parts, not the cover.

Answer (score 4):

You may be overall better off looking at replacing the fixtures with something different rather than stressing out trying to find an matching cover. It is fairly easy to source fixture covers that look more like this:

[image]

These also more of a contemporary styling as well.

Another thing to consider is the replacement to LED technology for the energy savings that it offers.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. We'll probably have to go that route. I just like the ones we have, they match the style of the room nicely.